# Keyword Functionality like Stackoverflows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have several entries (that will grow into thousands) in a database that I want to be able to index via keywords.

So say I have a table such as:

id | username | email | description

And I want to attach multiple keywords to that user such as:

Tall | Blonde | Male | Skinny

How would I structure the table for that? Much like the keywords used in stackoverflow at the bottom of the new question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need three tables

users:

```
id | username | email | description
```

tags: (will contain Tall, Blonde, Male, Skinny etc... in the name field)

```
id | name
```

users_tags:

```
user_id | tag_id
```

to make a user have a tag, you add a row to the `users_tags` table with the ids of the associated items.

both user_id and tag_id should be foreign keys, referring to the appropriate table, and combined, they should form a unique key (possibly primary key).

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, have 3 tables:

```
- users (user_id, username)
- keywords (keyword_id, keyword)
- user_keywords (user_id, keyword_id)
```

and have relations between them (on same column names as of in an example).

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship.

You have a table of keywords and a table of objects (which can be associated with keywords).

You then have a third table which has two columns which form a composite key, each of which is a foreign key on on of the other two tables.

e.g.

```
object_keyword_relationship
===========================
object_id    |   keyword_id
1            |   1
1            |   2
```